# How to get all the artifacts list from Azure feed

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts

How to get the list of all artifacts from Azure feed.
Below command is working fine, but getting only first 1000 artifacts.

`` @ReposList = `curl -u username\@abc.com:key -X GET "https://feeds.dev.azure.com/abc/ProjectName/_apis/packaging/Feeds/FeedName/packages?api-version=5.1-preview.1"`; ``

**But, how we can get rest of the artifacts as well ?**

Can some one help on this !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for Artifact Details - Get Packages: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/artifact-details/get-packages?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0.

There are a couple query parameters you can try passing to get all the artifacts.

`$top` is used in order to:

> Get the top N packages (or package versions where getTopPackageVersions=true)

You can try setting this to an arbitrarily high number and see if that returns the total number of artifacts you expected.

There is also `includeAllVersions` which works in the following way:

> True to return all versions of the package in the response. Default is false (latest version only).

I suggest using one (or both) and see if that helps resolve your situation.

Something like: `curl -u username\@abc.com:key -X GET "https://feeds.dev.azure.com/abc/ProjectName/_apis/packaging/Feeds/FeedName/packages&$top=5000&includeAllVersions=true?api-version=5.1-preview.1"`

Answer (score 0):

For powershell,it seems like:

```
$UriFeedPackageslist = "https://feeds.dev.azure.com/$orgName/$projectName/_apis/packaging/Feeds/$feed" + '/packages?$top=30000&api-version=7.0'
```